# Reference each occurence of a day of the month given start datetime and an end datetime

Tags: python, datetime

As the title says, I'm trying to generate a list of datetimes corresponding to the occurrences of a specific day of the month between two dates.

So given a start date, an end date, and a day of the month, I want to see every occurrence of that day of the month:

```
from datetime import datetime

end_date = datetime(2012, 9, 15, 0, 0)
start_date = datetime(2012, 6, 1, 0, 0)
day_of_month = 16

dates = "magic code goes here"
```

dates would then hold an array as such:

```
dates == [
datetime(2012, 6, 16, 0, 0),
datetime(2012, 7, 16, 0, 0),
datetime(2012, 8, 16, 0, 0)
]
```

The issue I'm running into is the number of checks I have to perform. First I have to check if it's the start year, if so, then I have to start at the beginning month, but if the day of the month is before the start date, then I have to skip that month. This same thing applies for the end of the period. Not to mention I have to check if the period starts and ends in the same year. All in all it's turning into quite a mess of nested `if` and `for` statements.

Here is my solution:

```
import numpy as np
for year in np.arange(start_date.year, end_date.year + 1):
    for month in np.arange(1, 13):
        date = datetime(year, month, day_of_month, 0, 0)
        if start_date < date < end_date:
            dates.append(date)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a succinct, but not efficient, way using [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html).

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

end_date = datetime(2012, 9, 15, 0, 0)
start_date = datetime(2012, 6, 1, 0, 0)
day_of_month = 16

rng = [i.to_pydatetime() for i in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='1D') if i.day == day_of_month]

# [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 16, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 16, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 16, 0, 0)]
```

Here is a more efficient method using a generator for the date range, which does not rely on `pandas`:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

rng = [i for i in daterange(start_date, end_date) if i.day == day_of_month]

# [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 16, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 16, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 16, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Just for clarification, this seems to perform the same as @DYZ solution in that it will iterate over each day between the two dates? Is there any benefit to using `pandas` given this?

Comment: `pandas` method isn't good because it builds the entire list of days (which could be very long) and then filters for ones with day = 16. The second method is roughly equivalent to @DYZ's solution, but you might get a small benefit from using list comprehension versus looping `list.append`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty (but reasonably efficient) solution:

```
import datetime
d = start_date
days = []
while d <= end_date: # Change to < if you do not want the end_date
    if d.day == day_of_month:
        days.append(d)
    d += datetime.timedelta(1)
days
# [datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 16, 0, 0), 
#  datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 16, 0, 0), 
#  datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 16, 0, 0)]
```

Ideally, you want to use `pandas` for this.

Comment: This solution makes a lot of sense. I'm not opposed to pandas as I'm using it elsewhere in this code. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @backlunp, i've added a `pandas` solution if it helps.